# Pandas plot data column on x axis

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot

I am trying to plot data using pandas. The data is as follows

```
Name 1999 2000 2001
stud1 11   22   33
stud2 33   44   55
stud3 55   66   77
......
```

I need to plot student mark year-wise (year is on x-axis).

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
df.pivot_table(columns=['Name']).plot()
```

It'll pivot your dataframe so that the year is the index and each student is a column

Comment: it would be nicer if you add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this this way

```
stud = pd.read_csv(r"C:/users/k_sego/students.csv", sep=";")
df = stud.pivot_table(columns=['Name'])
df.plot(kind='bar', legend=True)
```

[image]